# Equivalent of VLookup in VB6

Tags: vb6, excel, vba

Dear All,
I want to use the vlookup function in VB6. what is the code for it?
I am currently using this code:

```
WorkSheetName.Application.VLookup(20,WorkSheetName2.Range("A2:B20").Address,2,False)
```

WorkSheetName2 contains the lookup table. WorkSheetName is the sheet that contains a list of values to be looked up for their corresponding values from the lookup. 20 is an example of the value that I want to return its corresponding value from the lookup table.
The above code did not work. It returns empty.
 I also tried the following:

```
WorkSheetName.Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(20,WorksheetName.Range("A2:B20").Address,2,False)
```

This gave me an error and can't execute it. 
Please guide me.

Comment: Ups ... I erroneously posted a VBA answer ... and deleted it. Do you want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WorkSheetName.Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup( _
   20, WorkSheetName2.Range("A2:B20"), 2, False)
```